# What is wrong with my Postgresql Copy Command

Tags: sql, postgresql

COPY tableA
    FROM  'file.csv' WITH (DELIMITER as ',') CVS HEADER;

And the file is just a csv with a simple header.

Comment: So do you get any errors or are we supposed to guess what happens?

Comment: Nothing happened I did not get an error it just does not do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
COPY tableA FROM 'file.cvs' WITH DELIMITER as ',' CSV HEADER;
```

(I suppose the .cvs in the filename is also a typo, but hey! it is only a filename)